# LINQ query based on a filter with JOIN if value is not null

Tags: c#, linq, join, .net-4.0

I am trying to execute a LINQ query with JOIN of 2 tables and based on 2 filters, I want to skip filter if its value is null or empty.

```
callRecords = context.cti_ani_dnis
                .Join(context.transaction_details, cti => cti.trans_id, td => td.trans_id, (cti, td) => new { cti, td });
```

now I want to add a where clause but only if value of the filter is not null

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dnis) == false)
{
     callRecords = callRecords.Where(x => x.cti.dnis.Contains(dnis)); //getting error here
     //error is "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference"
}
```

I am getting that error and intellisense also doe snot show any option.
I have worked with queries like this but without join. I don't know how join will work here. can anybody help?

Comment: do you want yo filter something in `cti_ani_dnis` or `transaction_details`?. Maybe the whole class structure would help.

Comment: what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I have updated the original question with more detail.

Comment: what kind of type is `dnis`  passed as parameter in the contains?. I am assuming it is `string` and `cti.dnis`. is a collection of `strings`.

Comment: yes, string and therefore string.IsNullOrEmpty check.

Comment: What is your target .NET framework version?

Comment: What is the interface that `context.cti_ani_dnis` implements? Is it a plain `IEnumerable` or is it an `IEnumerable<SomeType>`? What does `SomeType.dnis` implement: `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: framework is 4.5

Comment: SomeType.dnis is a string

Comment: is it not possible?